# Moshe sees Hashem's back

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, shemot-exodus

Hashem tells Moshe that he can see His back not His face ([Shemot 33:23](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.33.23?lang=bi&aliyot=0)),some interpret this to mean that we cannot understand the future but we are at times able to understand things with hindsight, can someone provide a source for this interpretation? What source explains the verse this way? Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell us where you heard that interpretation?

Comment: I saw it a bunch online but with no source

Comment: on sites like this? https://torah.org/torah-portion/torah-thoughts-5767-kisisa/

Comment: yes exactly, you dont think theres a source?

Comment: I think that if that is a place where you saw it, asking them might be more direct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the Chasam Sofer on the posuk (among other possible sources I've heard the vort so many times that I doubt the Chasam Sofer is the only source but it is the only one that I know of)

Note: It's not an interpretation of the posuk. The Chasam Sofer says it is a remez (hint)

Comment: Source: https://www.sefaria.org/Chatam_Sofer_on_Torah%2C_Ki_Tisa.38?lang=he

Comment: thank you so so much!!